# OverflowError mktime argument out of range

Tags: python, django, mktime

After solving a naive datetime problem I am facing a new problem on a view to generate graphs. Now I get *mktime argument out of range*.
I have no idea how to solve it. I didn't write the code, I am using it from a colleague of mine and I can't seem o understand why it fails. I think it has to do with a function that runs overtime and the error pops out.

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def loggedin(request):
    data = []
    data2 = []
    data3 = []
    dicdata2 = {}
    dicdata3 = {}
    datainterior = []
    today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).date()
    tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
    semana= today - timedelta(7)
    today = today - timedelta(1)
    semana_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
    semana_start = timezone.make_aware(semana_start, timezone.utc)
    today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
    today_start = timezone.make_aware(today_start, timezone.utc)
    today_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time())
    today_end = timezone.make_aware(today_end, timezone.utc)
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("des_especialidade").distinct():
        dic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['des_especialidade'])
        dic["label"] = str(mod)
        dic["value"] = Repository.objects.filter(des_especialidade__iexact=mod).count()
        data.append(dic)
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
        dic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
        dic["label"] = str(mod)
        dic["value"] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod, dt_diag__gte=semana_start).count()
        datainterior.append(dic)
        # print mod, Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).count()
        # data[mod] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).count()
    dicdata2['values'] = datainterior
    dicdata2['key'] = "Cumulative Return"
    dicdata3['values'] = data
    dicdata3['color'] = "#d67777"
    dicdata3['key'] = "Diagnosticos Identificados"
    data3.append(dicdata3)
    data2.append(dicdata2)



    #-------sunburst
    databurst = []
    dictburst = {}
    dictburst['name'] = "CHP"
    childrenmodulo = []
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
        childrenmodulodic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
        childrenmodulodic['name'] = mod
        childrenesp = []
        for especialidade in Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod).values("des_especialidade").distinct():
            childrenespdic = {}
            esp = str(especialidade['des_especialidade'])
            childrenespdic['name'] = esp
            childrencode = []
            for code in Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod,des_especialidade__iexact=esp).values("cod_diagnosis").distinct():
                childrencodedic = {}
                codee= str(code['cod_diagnosis'])
                childrencodedic['name'] = 'ICD9 - '+codee
                childrencodedic['size'] = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod,des_especialidade__iexact=esp,cod_diagnosis__iexact=codee).count()
                childrencode.append(childrencodedic)
            childrenespdic['children'] = childrencode



            #childrenespdic['size'] = Repository.objects.filter(des_especialidade__iexact=esp).count()
            childrenesp.append(childrenespdic)
        childrenmodulodic['children'] = childrenesp
        childrenmodulo.append(childrenmodulodic)
    dictburst['children'] = childrenmodulo
    databurst.append(dictburst)
    # print databurst



    # --------stacked area chart
    datastack = []
    for modulo in Repository.objects.values("modulo").distinct():
        datastackdic = {}
        mod = str(modulo['modulo'])
        datastackdic['key'] = mod
        monthsarray = []
        year = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).year
        month = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)).month
        last = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()+timedelta(hours=1)) - relativedelta(years=1)
        lastyear = int(last.year)
        lastmonth = int(last.month)
        #i = 1
        while lastmonth <= int(month) or lastyear<int(year):
            date = str(lastmonth) + '/' + str(lastyear)
            if (lastmonth < 12):
                datef = str(lastmonth + 1) + '/' + str(lastyear)
            else:
                lastmonth = 01
                lastyear = int(lastyear)+1
                datef = str(lastmonth)+'/'+ str(lastyear)
                lastmonth = 0
            datainicial = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
            datainicial = timezone.make_aware(datainicial, timezone.utc)
            datafinal = datetime.strptime(datef, '%m/%Y')
            datafinal = timezone.make_aware(datafinal, timezone.utc)
            #print "lastmonth",lastmonth,"lastyear", lastyear
            #print "datainicial:",datainicial,"datafinal: ",datafinal
            filtro = Repository.objects.filter(modulo__iexact=mod)
            count = filtro.filter(dt_diag__gte=datainicial, dt_diag__lt=datafinal).count()
            conv = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y')
            ms = datetime_to_ms_str(conv)
            monthsarray.append([ms, count])
            #i += 1
            lastmonth += 1
        datastackdic['values'] = monthsarray
        datastack.append(datastackdic)
        #print datastack


    if request.user.last_login is not None:
        #print(request.user.last_login)
        contador_novas = Repository.objects.filter(dt_diag__lte=today_end, dt_diag__gte=today_start).count()
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                              {'user': request.user.username, 'contador': contador_novas, 'data': data, 'data2': data2,
                               'data3': data3,
                               'databurst': databurst, 'datastack':datastack})


def datetime_to_ms_str(dt):
    return str(1000 * mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

Comment: What is the value of `dt.timetuple()` that is causing the error?

Comment: Somewhere in 3001.
I can't figure out why the function goes on and on and on.

Comment: So the problem isn't really with mktime, it's the loop that isn't ending when you expect it to. What values did you get when you printed `lastmonth` and `lastyear` in each loop? What did you expect? Setting `lastmonth = 0` looks like a mistake to me.

Comment: The problem must be inside the `while loop`. The problem only exists when the month is = 12 that's why it was working until 01/12.
Anyway, I have no idea how to solve it. The main idea is to make a stacked area chart from last year's current month until this year's current month.
The loop doesn't stop and then it iterates over the years and months. No idea why.

I am sure the answer is straight forward but I can't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this condition.

```
while lastmonth <= int(month) or lastyear<int(year):
```

During December, `month=12`, so `lastmonth <= int(month)` will always be `True`. So the loop whill always return True, even once `lastyear` is more that the current `year`.

You want to loop if the loop is in the previous year, or if the loop is in the current year and the month is not in the future. Therefore, I think you want to change it to the following:

```
while lastyear < year or (lastyear == year and lastmonth <= month):
```

To be sure that the code is working and to understand it, you need to add lots of print statements to the loops, see how `lastmonth` and `lastyear` change, and check that the loop exits when you expect it to. You also need to test it for other values of `year` and `month` so that it doesn't break next month. Ideally you want to extract this bit of the code into a separate function. It would be easier to understand the loop if it only returned a list of `(month, year)` integers, instead of doing lots of date formatting at the same time. Then it would be easier to add unit tests.

Comment: You're a genius. It solved my problem. Now, please, could you explain why it did work like I was too dumb?

Comment: Actually, I think the answer I wrote before was wrong, and would only work during December. See my updated answer. The best way to understand the code is to add lots of print statements, and check that it works the way you expect.

Comment: Your last answer still works so I am gonna use that one. Anyway, I need to understand this logic thing because, in this case, I ma getting very confused.